# How to set multi-dimensional array in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on Twig for templating in my Symfony2 project. I need to define a 2 dimensional array. I tried like

```
{% set fields = { {'name': 'description', 'value':  '1'}, { 'name': 'abc', 'value': '2'}, { 'name':'tags', 'value': '3'} } %}
```

But I'm getting

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in ABundle:XYZ:edit_a_page.html.twig at line 51
```

Not sure what is wrong with the above code.

What is the right syntax to set a 2 dimensional array in twig?

Comment: Try thinking about `JSON` next time, TWIG nearly has the same array syntax

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Twig, arrays are marked with [], and hashes with {}. A hash is a key-value pair with explicit keys (strings or integers), an array is simply a set of values without any explicitly defined keys (they will be indexed numerically).

In order to use a hash, you MUST provide a key for each element.

So, what you want is probably `{% set fields = [ {'name': 'description', 'value':  '1'}, { 'name': 'abc', 'value': '2'}, { 'name':'tags', 'value': '3'} ] %}`

Comment: So how would you change the main key? At the moment it's still 0,1,2,3 etc.

Comment: If you want to set your own unique keys, use the hash syntax (outer curly braces rather than square brackets) and put the key followed by a colon before each one, as in user1529918's answer.  Also useful: Twig's [dump](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) function, to verify what it's seeing.

Comment: Hi, this may be a dumb question, but what class of object is this hash? It's just an associative array?

  Would json.decode('{{...},{....}}') make an object of the same class?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this
`{% set foo = {"adjuster_list": {"id": "1", "name": "Joe Smith"}} %}`

Comment: Or like this: **{% set foo = {"adjuster_list": [{"id": 1, "name": "Joe Smith"}]} %}**

Comment: That is helpful. Or it is in JSON style.